# Triple Play Test using PIC24 micro-controller

Tags: performance, microcontroller

Can anybody suggest me if I can program my device as Triple-Play-Tester?
My device has PIC24 processor and ENC28J60 chip. I am thinking can my micro-controller process the packets and measure the performance?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a device that generates network data streams that model those generated by a video / voice / internet delivery package,  I think you will need a lot more processor power (and more than 10Mbit/s) to handle typical flows.